# ttf-mscorefonts-installer gives "system problem detected"

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I was trying to get vlc to read encrypted dvds. So I was trying to get libdvdcss. I read somewhere (sorry, I can't remember more than what I am saying) that it came in a bundle package, so I apt installed the bundle. Or tried to. Suddenly, I was asked to accept some EULA licence for microsoft fonts. I didn't want to, and I didn't need these fonts, so, as there was no other option except "OK" I closed the terminal window.

I started getting "System problem detected" error messages each time I turned on the computer. When I looked in /var/crash I saw they were caused by ttf-mscore-installer. I tried to remove it, it said "no such package". I installed it and then ran

```
sudo apt remove --purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt autoremove
```

This removed a lot of packages. I rebooted and saw "System problem detected" again. This time there are 2 problematic packages, ttf-mscore-installer.0.crash and _usr_bin_pcmanfm.1000.crash

Please tell me which command is more powerfull than apt remove --purge? Which command would remove all traces of ttf-mscore-installer from my system?

Comment: Your issue is, I suspect, unrelated to `ttf-mscore-installer`, but a consequence of you closing the terminal during package installs. You can reject the EULA required from microsoft and have the install continue (*without the microsoft fonts of course*) but you didn't do this, instead closing the window & thus not letting package installs complete & subsequent cleanup. You've not provided any OS/release thus I'm restricted to being *generic*, but have you tried to fix your package issues?  What OS & release are you running?

Comment: I'm using Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish). I was asked to accept microsolf EULA licence. I read later that if you first use tab to highlight "OK" and press enter, you then see another screen which asks you whether you agree to this licence, with yes and no options. But I didn't know this at the time, the only option was "OK". I tried "escape", "control-C", nothing got rid of this question, so I had to close the terminal.

Comment: You can check the logs in /var/log/apt/ to see what you actually tried to install and add that to your question. IIRC it should just have been `libdvd-pkg` and I don't recall that installing fonts.